# Project with Google Drive API? Is it doable?

Tags: google-drive-api

I've been thinking about a project I'd like to start using the Google Drive API. My idea was to make a webpage (using Laravel) to let guests download files. I'd have 3 different types of users: the guests, that would be able to download files, the logged in users, that would be able to upload files, and the admins, which would be able to do all of that plus delete files (these files would be PDFs only).

Also, the server it would run on wouldn't have a lot of hard drive space for storing the files, it would just host the page and maybe keep some of the most important files. But the thing is, I have no experience whatsoever with this API. And I would hate to go through all of this trouble just to discover that it can't be done. I've tried reading the documentation but I still don't know if this is doable, and I can't find reliable tutorials (also, I don't know what is reliable, I've never worked with it).

So, for anyone who has already done something with the API, is this doable? Will the download speeds be too slow? Will users without accounts be able to download? Also, do you know any tutorials that are reliable and do it the right way? Or is the documentation the only thing I'll find/need?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
All three cases can be handled with google drive sdk. You need to explore API in depth. Creation and downloads are easy and upload is tricky.

I recently used google drive api in a chrome extension that uploads images directly to drive [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/image-saver/ipkkcbhjiafgdhjaincandbahdknhpel)

You can ask questions regarding api usages here.

Comment: I mean you can ask questions at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, I would suggest going through one of the given Quickstarts in [Google Drive REST API Overview](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk).

Secondly, please note of the [Requirements and Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/requirements#top_of_page) that a Drive API integration must adopt.
As mentioned:

> **Requirements**
>
> - Following an "open with" action, applications must check that the user is authorized to read/write the document to which the passed document ID refers.
>
> **Best practices**
>
> - In the "create new" flow, Google Drive provides your application with an authorization code. This code should be upgraded to an access token as soon as possible before applications take other actions.

Lastly, this SO post - [Good tutorial on Google Drive SDK and OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966397/good-tutorial-on-google-drive-sdk-and-oauth-2) might also help.